# Mysql Count distinct using group by

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

Hi I'm having a strange result back from a query I'm running.

I can run this query and get the correct result:

```
SELECT `Call_Type`, COUNT(DISTINCT(Phone)) as Phone
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Call_Type ;
```

and my result which looks correct:

```
Call_Type   Phone
SET1        3806773
SET2        2757896
SET3        1847154
Set4        1722314
```

Now I'm running the same query using a different column and I get the results back but only 1 set has a figure in it which shouldn't be the case.

```
SELECT call_type, COUNT(DISTINCT(surpost)) as Surpost
FROM table1
GROUP BY Call_Type ;
```

and the results look like:

```
call_type   Surpost
SET1        0
SET2        0
SET3        0
SET4        1677105
```

Any help on why the results are coming back like this and how can I fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Raw Table Data Example:

```
Firstname   Surname Postcode    Phone   Call_Type   SurPost Outcome_Description Last_Call
Azzedine    Adaba   XXX XXX 7940036000  SET4    AdabaXXXXXX Failed 19/05/2014 12:23
Azzedine    Adaba   XXX XXX 2085811000  SET3    AdabaXXXXXX No Answer 10/02/2014 15:32
Azzedine    Adaba   XXX XXX 7940036000  SET4    AdabaXXXXXX Unknown 21/05/2014 18:59
Nadir       Adaba   XXX XXX 7923135000  SET4    AdabaXXXXXX Hung Up 30/08/2013 11:50
Nadir       Adaba   XXX XXX 7923135000  SET3    AdabaXXXXXX No Answer 18/09/2013 18:02
Nadir       Adaba   XXX XXX 7923135000  SET3    AdabaXXXXXX Operator intercept  19/02/2014 18:47
```

Stuart

Comment: Post your data and desired output.

Comment: difference in `Call_Type`

Comment: `count` of *specific column* won't count if the column has all `NULL` entries and hence returns a `zero`. Similarly if some of the entries have values `count` will only counts that many rows.

Comment: The table has 23 Million rows I can post an example dataset but will need to remove customer details.

Comment: You have null values in `surpost`. Try this query to show how many are null: `select call_type, count(*) from table1 where call_type is null group by 1`